# elasticsearch spring not return exact match

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I'm doing Full text search using elastic search on Java API. The object is to match each words of the query String with the field(Operator And), and be able to recognize and match the plural form of the words.

For exemple:

`Four salé` should find `Fours salés`, meanwhile `Four sucré` should not be found. (My docs are in French)

I've tried several way to solve this:

```
QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field",queryValue)
```

This code can find a word's single or plural form, but returns all results that match one of words of the queryValue.

```
QueryBuilders.mathcQuery("field",queryValue).operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND)
```

This code can give results that match every word, but it don't do the world stemming of plurals.

I've also tried several analyzer that differs from the default one, like "snowball", "french". Strangely enough, they don't return results of perfect match for some words.

Could anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: Probably changing the UTF encoding may work. Also you may try the filters to make searching specific to documents and fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact match of the field, you should make your field `not_analyzed`. Checkout: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_query_with_text

Comment: Is that suffice to mention the field as `@Field(type=FieldType.Keyword)`

Comment: This link may be helpful [link](https://github.com/linkmesrl/elasticsearch-odm-5/issues/7)